# Trying to make a php POST request to bayimg with a pic

Tags: php, http, post, request

Hi Im trying to automate the upload of pictures to imgbay... seeing the request that is generated from the browser with wireshark and seeing this  [post](http://vedovini.net/2009/08/posting-multipart-form-data-using-php/) I came up with this.

```
$destination = "http://bayimg.com";


$eol = "\r\n";
$data = '';




$str=file_get_contents('umbered1.jpg');

$mime_boundary='-------------------------'. time();

$data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file;"';
$data .= 'filename="umbered1.jpg"' . $eol;
$data .= 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' . $eol . $eol;
$data .= $str. $eol;
$data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"' . $eol;
$data .= 'bla';
$data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$data .= 'Content-Type: form-data; name="tags"' . $eol;
$data .= '--' .$mime_boundary . $eol.$eol;


$params = array('http' => array(
                  'method' => 'POST /upload',
                  'protocol_version' => '1.1',
                  'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'. $eol .
                                'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'. $eol .
                                'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' . $eol .
                                'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' . $eol .
                                'Referer: http://bayimg.com/' . $eol . 
                                'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='. $mime_boundary. $eol .
                                 "Content-Length: " . strlen($data). $eol,
                  'content' => $data
               ));

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
echo $response = @file_get_contents($destination, 0, $ctx);
```

what I see in wireshark is this

```
 POST /upload / HTTP/1.1

 Host: bayimg.com

 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0

 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

 Referer: http://bayimg.com/

 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------1409116238

 Content-Length: 12681



 ---------------------------1409116238

 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file;"filename="umbered1.jpg"

 Content-Type: image/jpeg

 //Here comes the image data....

 ---------------------------1409116238

 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"

 bla---------------------------1409116238

 Content-Type: form-data; name="tags"

 ---------------------------1409116238



 HTTP/1.1 200 OK

 Server: nginx/1.6.0

 Date: Wed, 27 Aug 2014 05:10:41 GMT

 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

 Connection: keep-alive

 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.0RC3

 Set-Cookie: country=AR; expires=Wed, 03-Sep-2014 05:10:41 GMT; Max-Age=604800

 Content-Encoding: gzip
```

// the response is an error page

///// end of packet

The server responds but its an error....

this is what I get when I upload the image via the web.

```
 POST /upload HTTP/1.1

 Host: bayimg.com

 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0

 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

 Referer: http://bayimg.com/

 Cookie: country=AR; __PPU_SESSION_4-7=X54717,1408841107,0,0X

 Connection: keep-alive

 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------51442902223623

 Content-Length: 12721



 -----------------------------51442902223623

 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="umbered1.jpg"

 Content-Type: image/jpeg

 /// here comes the image data

 -----------------------------51442902223623

 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"



 bla

 -----------------------------51442902223623

 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tags"





 -----------------------------51442902223623--

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK

 Server: nginx/1.6.0

 Date: Wed, 27 Aug 2014 05:18:50 GMT

 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

 Connection: keep-alive

 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.0RC3

 Content-Encoding: gzip
```

// the response is a error page

I see that I am not using the Cookies but I don't know how to set them. I also tried with curl but this is the closes that i get to replicate the header... any help will be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are way over thinking this. Try this instead:

```
<?php 

    $url  = 'http://bayimg.com/upload';
    $file = 'umbered1.jpg';
    $code = 'YourRemovalCode';
    $tags = 'Space Separated Tags';

    $data = array(
        'code' => $code,
        'tags' => $tags,
        'file' => '@' . $file
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

To be honest, I didn't think they'd allow just anyone to POST images to the site, but apparently so. Enjoy!

> **EDIT: If you are uising PHP 5.5 or greater, try this version:**

```
$url  = 'http://bayimg.com/upload';
$file = 'umbered1.jpg';
$code = 'YourRemovalCode';
$tags = 'Space Separated Tags';

// No need to change anything from here on.
$mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file));
$data = array(
    'code' => $code,
    'tags' => $tags,
    'file' => new CurlFile($file, $mime)
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: I tried your code and my php server tells me that the 'file' => '@' . $file is deprecated... so i changed it but it does not generate any POST request.. don't know why...

Comment: Ah, OK. Changes in PHP 5.5. Give me a minute and I will do an adjusted code sample.

Comment: Man!! you are right!! your code works! Just added urlencode to the objects of the array and curl sent the POST request! Thank you very much!

Comment: Try out the new version for 5.5 that I just added. You should not (and really should avoid) urlencoding() the array at all, but there should be no reason to even try it now.